# Haskell possible make own type instance of Text

Tags: haskell, types, io, appendfile

Noob here again. Getting my feet wet in making my own Haskell 'programs'. Stumbled across this. 
Made my own type:

```
data Action = Action 
  { idN         :: IdN
  , description :: Desc 
  , duedate     :: Due 
  , donedate    :: Done 
  } deriving (Ord, Show, Read, Eq)
```

Imported `Data.Text.IO`. Want to write concrete info in `Action` to file using

```
TIO.appendFile "./Dbase.txt" typedAction
```

where `typedAction` is the concrete representation of the `Action` type. Now `Action` is not of type `Text`.
So how would I go about this?

Comment: Do you mean typedAction :: Action ? in which case, (T.pack . show $ typedAction) would work. Alternatively, with the text-show package, (showt typedAction)

Comment: Thanks. That works as an intermediate solution if I were to use that and eventually store that using `TIO.appendFile`, but it is a bit of a hassle compared to directly writing the `Action` type and concrete content to file

Comment: It's unclear what you mean @Madderote. Do you wish to store it in eg. JSON so that you can load it back from the file? Your title suggests you don't understand the difference between types and typeclasses; Text is a type so it doesn't have instances.

Comment: I understand the difference. Figured it out already thanks to your comment! If I save as 'shown' it saves the complete concrete type record syntax. That's nice if you stay within Haskell, but I need a uniform text file, so won't work. It works if I use the type `Action` in Haskell, deconstruct it for storage and reconstruct it when reading.

Comment: You can serialize your class however you want.  The instance of `Show` will give you a default behavior to make a string out of your class, but you've chosen to use the default instance.  You could either remove the `deriving Show` and make `Action` an instance of `Show` with your own `show` function, or you could write another function that turns an `Action` into `Text`.

Comment: So are you asking 1. How do I serialize a value, such as `Action` (ex to JSON or another format)?  2. How do I write such a serialized value to disk?

Or alternatively: what does it mean to you to "directly writ[e] the `Action`"?  What would be placed in the file if not the text obtained from `show someAction`?